# Retrieving the bare text at a particular URL emacs

Tags: emacs, urlfetch

Before posting this question I tried to using `browse-url-emacs` and `C-x C-f` but in vain.

The question: Is it possible to retrieve the entire text at a particular url or even the entire server response of a url request? I.e. instead of downloading and then opening a file in emacs, just pass in `http(s)://path.to.text.el.py.html.etc/` to some built-in command and get the entire response or the text in a new buffer? Or better still just drag-n-drop the url inside emacs?

Comment: `browse-url-emacs` should do this. How did it fail?

Comment: The backtrack pastebin.com/8BiB7kFD

Comment: I am actually encountering some intermittent issues with `browse-url-emacs`, however not the error you're seeing, and I don't know much about the URL handling in Emacs. Which platform & version of Emacs are you using?

Comment: `browse-url-emacs` works for me...?

Comment: @phils I am using Emacs 24.1(x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) on Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: @Cheeso how would I know if it works for you or not?

Comment: hus787: and does `browse-url-emacs` fail in general (with any URL)?

Comment: @phils Well, I tried http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/icicles.el and http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt Same issue.

Comment: Is it different if you start emacs with `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: nope. *meeting-the-minimum-comment-length*

Comment: I'm really not sure, in that case. I can only suggest trying the slightly newer 24.2 (or the latest from version control).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to *Emacs 24.3.1* fixes this unusual bug/problem.